# Stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Can I use only one stored procedure for many queries?

Like this:

```
SELECT @var_name[0] from @table_name WHERE @con1 = @var_name[1] ;
```

Comment: **WHY?!?** A good stored procedure should be - like any code snippet - focused on one and only one, clearly defined task. If you have 10 different tasks - why squeeze everything into a single procedure? Doesn't make any sense at all - from a maintainability perspective, these "do-it-all" procedures that do all sorts of different things, depending on their input parameters, are a total nightmare. **Don't do it!** Don't even think about it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. You could build the query dyamically with something like

```
EXEC('SELECT ' + @var_name + ' FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE ' + @Con1 + ' = ' + @var_name)
```

Be aware of potential performance and sql injection issues when doing this though.